# Getting products to appear if customer hasn't reached free delivery amount

Tags: cart, if

I want to get a few products to display if a user hasnt reached our free delivery target (£75 excl VAT) so i tried to write in an IF statement in my cart.phtml file however i am not great at coding but i did give it a try so if someone could help me out that would be great.

This is my cart.phtml file

```
<div class="cart">
    <div class="page-title title-buttons">
        <h1><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Cart') ?></h1>
        <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
        <ul class="checkout-types">
        <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('top_methods') as $method): ?>
            <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
            <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form_before') ?>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>" method="post">
    <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <table id="shopping-cart-table" class="data-table cart-table">
                <col width="1" />
                <col />
                <col width="1" />
            <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceExclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartPriceInclTax() || $this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                <col width="1" />
            <?php endif; ?>
                <col width="1" />

            <?php $mergedCells = ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices() ? 2 : 1); ?>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td-image" rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>">&nbsp;</th>
                        <th class="td-name" rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></span></th>
                        <th class="td-edit" rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"></th>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllowInCart()) : ?>
                        <th class="td-wishlist" rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Move to Wishlist') ?></span></th>
                        <?php endif ?>
                        <th class="td-price" class="a-center" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Unit Price') ?></span></th>
                        <th class="td-qty" rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
                        <th class="td-price" class="a-center" colspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Subtotal') ?></th>
                        <th class="td-delete" rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="a-center">&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('tax')->displayCartBothPrices()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                        <th class="a-right"><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(false) ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $this->helper('tax')->getIncExcTaxLabel(true) ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="50" class="a-right">
                            <?php if(Mage::getUrl()): ?>
                                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button button_white btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart') ?>" class="button button_white btn-update"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Update Shopping Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('shopping-cart-table')</script>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    <div class="cart-collaterals row clearfix">
        <div class="grid_4">
            <?php if (!$this->getIsVirtual()): echo '<div class="cart-block cart-shipping">'.$this->getChildHtml('shipping').'</div>'; endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4">
            <div class="cart-block cart-coupon">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('coupon') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_4">
            <div class="cart-block cart-total">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('totals'); ?>
                <?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
                <ul class="checkout-types">
                <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>
                    <?php if ($methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method)): ?>
                    <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('crosssell') ?>
</div>
```

and this is the code i tried to check if the sub total was above 75.00 or not

```
    <div class="upsell">

    <?php if ($this->__('Subtotal') < 75.00)
        {
         echo "Why not add these products to qualify for Free Delivery";

        }?>
        </div>
```

But that didnt work, my theory behind this was that $this->__('Subtotal') displays the subtotal so i thought i could just pass that in and check if it was under 75.00 apparently not (or i just did it the wrong way).

if you could help would be much appreciated.

So to recap i want my IF statement to take in the subtotal, check if the subtotal is under 75.00 if so display a message.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$this->__('...')` is a translation function.  It takes whatever string you provide (`Subtotal`) and translates it to another language if necessary.  Your code is essentially comparing the literal text `Subtotal` to the number `75.00`, which is why it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()` in your IF instead of `$this->__('Subtotal')`. There is a lot to explain here, but basically you used the label of the price as the price variable.

You might want to dump the variable i gave you first to see the format and the type of data it returns, to be able to compare it with your price.

Comment: had to change GrandTotal to Subtotal but it worked brilliantly. Thank you